# Populating other fields after selecting a input from autocomplete options using angular and javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to edit user details where on selecting user name all other details may be populated by default on input using AngularJS and Javascript.

I dont want to use PHP as it is purely a desktop app.

Comment: On clicking the username, make a call to server to fetch it's details and display it

Comment: Show us what you have done so far?

Comment: @FortuneEkeruo  I have been able to display details of single person in a table row.But the problem is i need to create a controller for each row in table to display correct data.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please post some basic code which you have written to get help

Comment: This question is really unclear, and too broad.  I voted to close the question as too broad, however, because your question implies that you want someone to show you how to write the component, rather than someone to help you solve a specific problem with your code.

Comment: also, your comment that you "need to create a controller for each row in table" doesn't really make sense, and sounds more like you are misunderstanding some angular fundamentals.